# Access to raw arguments of Node.js script on Windows

Tags: node.js, arguments, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

Node.js substitute argument looked like path as complete path in Windows environment.

```
$ node -e 'console.log(process.argv)' /arg1
```

Output:

```
[ 'c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
  'C:/Program Files (x86)/Git/arg1' ]
```

This substitution doesn't occur in OSX and Linux environments.

How I can get actual content of CLI argument on Windows?

Comment: That's likely due to the CLI itself. Which are you using? Command Prompt: `[ 'node', '/arg1' ]`. PowerShell 2: `[ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe', '/arg1' ]`. You might try quoting the arguments: `node -e '...' '/arg1'`.

Comment: Seems to be true. Standart Windows cmd.exe output correct data. I'm using Git Bash. Looks like it process arguments in special way.

@JonathanLonowski Thanks for you comment!